# How to save two transaction in my shopping cart

Tags: php

i have two transaction on my cart.

while i click checkout, why $grand total only one inserted to my db.
and when i echo $grand, it appear two total.

this is my function

```
function cart(){
    $username = $_SESSION['UserID'];
    $cart = array();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE Username='$username'");

    while ($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $cart[] = $r;
    }
    return $cart;
}
```

this is my process code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
    echo $start= $cart[$i]['City_Saler'];
    echo $end= $cart[$i]['City_Cust'];
    $price= $cart[$i]['Price'];
    $gram= $cart[$i]['gram'] / 1000;
    echo $kg= ceil($gram);

  $query= mysql_query("select * FROM service WHERE Start_Destination='$start' AND End_Destination='$end'");
  while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

      $grand=$query_row['ServPriceKG'] + $price ;  

  }
} 

for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ordering_detail(ID_Transaction, ID_Product, User_ID, Service_Name, Service_Package, Qty, gram, Price, Receiver_Name, Receiver_City, Receiver_Subdis, Receiver_Address, Receiver_Prov, Receiver_Phone, Grandtotal, Payment, Stat_Transfer_Item, ID_Saler)

  VALUES('$idtransaction', '{$cart[$i]['ID_Product']}', '$cusid', '$service', '$paket', '{$cart[$i]['qty']}', '$kg', '{$cart[$i]['Price']}', '$name', '$reci', '$subdis',  '$address', '$prov', '$phone',  '$grand', '-', '-', '{$cart[$i]['ID_Saler']}')");
}

      mysql_query("DELETE FROM preview_ordering WHERE ID_Preview= '$id'");


for ($i = 0; $i < $j; $i++) { mysql_query("DELETE FROM cart WHERE ID = {$cart[$i]['ID']}");}

header('Location:cart.php');
```

please help me out

Comment: Is your "ordering_detail" supposed to be inserted as a loop? Really seems like you should have a single order table that joins to a "products in order" table.

Comment: Yes cause I take it from my function

Comment: Why I need another table join? The only want to add is ordering_detail

Comment: Sorry the problem only in code place...

Comment: It should places in the bracket looping before..

Comment: Thank you for trying help me out :)

Comment: I'm sorry but the approach you've taken to build up your order is a little confusing, I can see $price is used but it's being defined in the loop by the last item only. I think you need to clean up your code so you can trace exactly what you're doing.